# UI component form with a foreign key value

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, forms, uicomponent

I'm trying to do a admin form for a custom model, this model has 3 foreign key columns, I using UI component for this, but i haven't got idea.

For example, this model has a order_id column, i'm passing order id in the controller and load needed order info in DataProvider, and add this info to returned data, but don't show any info in form.

**class DataProvider**

```
<?php

...

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{

protected $loadedData;
protected $dataPersistor;

/**
 * @var CollectionFactory\
 */
protected $collection;
protected $orderRepository;
protected $_request;


/**
 * DataProvider constructor.
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $primaryFieldName
 * @param string $requestFieldName
 * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
 * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
 * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
 * @param RequestInterface $request
 * @param array $meta
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    $name,
    $primaryFieldName,
    $requestFieldName,
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
    OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    RequestInterface $request,
    array $meta = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->_request = $request;
    parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
}

/**
 * Get data
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }

    $orderId = $this->_request->getParam('order_id');
    if(! empty($orderId)){
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
    }

    $items = $this->collection->getItems();
    foreach ($items as $model) {
        $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
    }
    $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('rma_entity');

    if (!empty($data)) {
        $model = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
        $model->setData($data);
        $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
        $this->dataPersistor->clear('rma_entity');
    }

    if(!empty($order)){
        $this->loadedData = array(
            'order_id' => $order->getEntityId(),
            'customer_id' => $order->getCustomerId(),
            'customer_name' => $order->getCustomerFirstname(),
            'customer_email' => $order->getCustomerEmail()
        );
    }

    return $this->loadedData;
}
}
```

**class Edit**, Controller to show form

```
<?php

...

class Edit extends \EMP\Rma\Controller\Adminhtml\Entity
{

protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry);
}

/**
 * Edit action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
 */
public function execute()
{
    // 1. Get ID and create model
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id');
    /** @var Entity $model */
    $model = $this->_objectManager->create('EMP\Rma\Model\Entity');

    // 2. Initial checking
    if ($id) {
        $model->load($id);
        if (!$model->getId()) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This RMA no longer exists.'));
            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        }
    }
    $this->_coreRegistry->register('rma_entity', $model);

    // 5. Build edit form
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $this->initPage($resultPage)->addBreadcrumb(
        $id ? __('Edit RMA') : __('New RMA'),
        $id ? __('Edit RMA') : __('New RMA')
    );

    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('RMAs'));
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($model->getId() ? $model->getTitle() : __('New RMA'));
    return $resultPage;
}
}
```

Thank for the help :)